# Javascript to check a textbox for a certain word

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement, textbox

Okay so I'm trying to make a small little Javascript puzzle for a junior assignment, and I've only ever worked with number checking in text boxes, so excuse me if this seems slightly dumb.

Anyway, what I am trying to do is to check a textbox for a certain word, a password as you may, to advance to the next "level"

My Code:

```js
var timesClicked = 100;

//Function to run the window alert a certain amount of times, as well as hide a certain answer
function changeFunc() {
 
 if (timesClicked > 0){

  if (timesClicked == 50) {
   window.alert("N34T");
   timesClicked--;
   changeFunc();
  }

  else {
   window.alert("NEAT");
   timesClicked--;
   changeFunc();
  }
 }
 else{

  window.alert("Sorry, no more answers may be dispensed at this time!");
 }
}

//Function to go to the next puzzle
function nextPuzzle(){
 
 if (document.getElementById('answer').value.indexOf("N34T") > -1) {
  window.alert("Good Job");
  window.location.href="puzzle02.html";
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="puzzle01.js">
  </script>
  
  <title>Puzzle 1</title>
 </head>
 <header>
 <h1>Puzzle 1!</h1>
  <p> Please enjoy this puzzle's easiness, they will get harder!</p><br>
 </header>
 <body>
  <p>

  <input type="text" id="answer">
  <button type="button" onclick="nextPuzzle()">Next Puzzle</button><br><br>
  
  <button type="button" onclick="changeFunc()">Answers!</button>
  </p>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

This statement:

> if (document.getElementById('answer').value.indexOf("N34T") > -1)

won't run with the correct word in the text box.

Can anyone help? Thanks to anyone who can help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your second puzzle on an independent page (let's say, `puzzle2.html`), you simply assign this to **[`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)** in the `'Good Job'` conditional:

```
window.location = "puzzle2.html";
```

This can be seen in the following:

```js
var timesClicked = 100;

//Function to run the window alert a certain amount of times, as well as hide a certain answer
function changeFunc() {
  if (timesClicked > 0) {
    if (timesClicked == 50) {
      window.alert("N34T");
      timesClicked--;
      changeFunc();
    } else {
      window.alert("NEAT");
      timesClicked--;
      changeFunc();
    }
  } else {
    window.alert("Sorry, no more answers may be dispensed at this time!");
  }
}

//Function to go to the next puzzle
function nextPuzzle() {
  if (document.getElementById('answer').value.indexOf("N34T") > -1) {
    window.alert("Good Job");
    window.location = "puzzle2.html";
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>
    <input type="text" id="answer">
    <button type="button" onclick="nextPuzzle()">Next Puzzle</button><br><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="changeFunc()">Answers!</button>
  </p>
</body>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful for later use, but not for current problem. Thanks much though! :)

Answer (score 0):

First, there need a `}` in your `nextPuzzle` function;
Second, if you want to use the `onclick` DOM event, you should define the function in the head, or you can use `addEventListener` for bind event handler.

```js
var timesClicked = 100;

//Function to run the window alert a certain amount of times, as well as hide a certain answer
function changeFunc() {
 
 if (timesClicked > 0){

  if (timesClicked == 50) {
   window.alert("N34T");
   timesClicked--;
   changeFunc();
  }

  else {
   window.alert("NEAT");
   timesClicked--;
   changeFunc();
  }
 }
 else{

  window.alert("Sorry, no more answers may be dispensed at this time!");

 }
   
}



//Function to go to the next puzzle
function nextPuzzle(){
 if (document.getElementById('answer').value.indexOf("N34T") > -1) {
  window.alert("Good Job");
  }
  
}

document.querySelector('.next-puzzle').addEventListener('click', nextPuzzle);
document.querySelector('.change').addEventListener('click', changeFunc);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="puzzle01.js">
  </script>
  
  <title>Puzzle 1</title>
 </head>
 <header>
 <h1>Puzzle 1!</h1>
  <p> Please enjoy this puzzle's easiness, they will get harder!</p><br>
 </header>
 <body>
  <p>

  <input type="text" id="answer" />
  <button type="button" class="next-puzzle">Next Puzzle</button><br><br>
  
  <button type="button" class="change">Answers!</button>
  </p>
  
 </body>
 




</html>
```

Comment: Okay so I did this in my code, and the if statement still doesn't work... Any other Ideas? Also, thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Is your word check of the requirement case sensitivity?